# Make an IconButton Drawer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, navigation-drawer, drawer

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Drawer() {

    val items = listOf(

    DrawerItem(
        Icons.Default.Favorite,
        "Favourite"
    ),
    DrawerItem(
        Icons.Default.Add,
        "Add"
    ),
    DrawerItem(
        Icons.Default.AccountBox,
        "Account"
    )
)


    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val selectedItem = remember{
        mutableStateOf(items[0])
    }
    
    ModalNavigationDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
                        ModalDrawerSheet{
                            Image(
                                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.globologo),
                                contentDescription = "Header Image",
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .height(150.dp).padding(all = 10.dp),
                                contentScale = ContentScale.Inside
                            )
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                            items.forEach{
                                    item ->
                                NavigationDrawerItem(
                                    label = {
                                       Text(text = item.title)
                                    },
                                    selected = selectedItem.value == item,
                                    icon = {
                                        Icon(
                                            imageVector = item.imageVector,
                                            contentDescription = item.title
                                        )
                                           },
                                    onClick = {
                                        scope.launch {
                                            selectedItem.value = item
                                            drawerState.close()
                                        }
                                    }
                                )
                            }
                        }
        },

        content = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
            ){
                IconButton(onClick = {
                    scope.launch {
                        drawerState.open()
                    }
                }
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.hamburgermenu),
                        contentDescription = "Menu",
                        modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
                    )
                }
            }

        }


    )


}




data class DrawerItem(
    val imageVector : ImageVector,
    val title: String
)
```

My drawer appears like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XilLk.png)

I want to have just the icon for add it later in the TopAppBar, to appear like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp0pQ.png)

I've tried to add the Drawer Function to the TopAppBar Row didn't work, as it appears like the first image and hide the TopAppBar.
Thank you Previously!